# HTML help I can't figure this out

Tags: html, css, image, icons

Okay I cannot figure out what's going on as it works fine on my computer, yet when I try it out on my hosting, it doesn't wanna cooperate. My website is http://kamecomputers.com/ and the issue is in the little circles where I'm supposed to have some icons, now on my computer they work fine, but I just doesn't wanna work on the hosting. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5ayV.jpg)Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ?What circles where is it? Can you take a little more effort to paste the screen shot of where these small circles are ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links to the images are broken. Here is what you have:

```
background: url(\Images\wrench.png) no-repeat center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

You are using a backslash (`\`) when you're likely wanting to use a forward slash (`/`).

http://kamecomputers.com/Images/wrench.png

Comment: @Madcat3277 - great avatar and be sure to mark the question as resolved ([by selecting a correct answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)) if the issue was solved.